# Creating an array of UIViews

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I am stumped creating an array of UIViews I have in my code. I created a chess board and each square is a UIView. In my UIViewController class declaration I have the following --

```
@interface ChessViewController : UIViewController
{
    ChessSquareView   *squares[64];
}
```

In the .m file I am creating the views for each of the 64 squares in a for loop like this --

```
for ( int i=0; i<64; i++)
    squares[i] = [ [ChessSquareView alloc] initWithFrame:sq];
```

where `sq` is the position and dimensions (`CGRect`) for that square. In the ChessSquareView.m file I am storing the `CGRect` in a variable. I am printing them out in the initWithFrame function to make sure I am adding the correct values.

Later on in the code (for e.g. the touchEnded function) I am looping through the array of views and finding that the objects are all wrong. What is the correct way to create the array of UIViews?

EDIT:

To clarify in the touchEnded function  I am looping through the views to figure where the user tapped. In that function I print out the `frame` for each view using `NSStringFromCGRect` function and they are all wrong.

```
for (int i=0; i<25; i++)
{
    NSLog(@"Checking Square %@", NSStringFromCGRect([squares[i] frame]));

}
```

Comment: 1. do the UIViews get placed correctly ? Try to put some random colors into the UIView's backgroundColor property when you add them & see this first. 

2. You need to convert the position into UIView's coordinate system first.

Comment: @nsuinteger - the UIViews are getting placed correctly. I have changed the question as I am now convinced its an array creation issue.

Comment: Use NSArray, not C array. NSArray is for objects; it has useful methods for access and manipulation, and memory is managed correctly.

Comment: If the views are visible and at the correct location, then I'm not understanding the claim that the frames are wrong. Perhaps give an example of the initial frame for a square vs. the frame in touchesEnded.

Comment: first of all I'd say 'better' use Objective-C arrays instead of C arrays even though I dont see anything very wrong in what you have done & since you say the views are getting placed correctly there doesnt seems to be anything wrong in array creation. Could you give some information where you say "Later on in the code (for e.g. the touchEnded function) I am looping through the array of views and finding that the objects are all wrong." ?

Comment: I added clarification in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In .h:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *squares;
```

In .m

```
self.squares = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for(int i = 0; i < 64; i++)
{
    ChessSquareView *v = [[ChessSquareView alloc] initWithFrame:sq];
    [self.squares addObject:v];
}
```

Comment: what's the difference between creating a variable using the property and directly declaring it like I did (assuming I also crated a NSMutableArray)? Also I will read the docs and figure out how to dealloc it.

Comment: This is just the objective-c way of creating an array. I tried the c way and it doesn't seem to respond to any of the same methods as NSMutableArray (or NSArray). I think it's 'safest' to use an objective-c object in this case, especially if you set it as a property - in that case all the memory management will be handled for you, provided you are using ARC.

Comment: Ah so if I create it as a property the memory management is done automatically?

Comment: Yes, 'automatically' in the sense that retain/release/autorelease is inserted for you. You still have to make sure you don't cause retain cycles and set strongly referenced objects to nil when you are done with them so they can be released.

Answer (score 0):

Like the others, I would suggest using an NSMutableArray rather than a C array. Even still, the C array should work.

However, the code you posted is using the same value for the frame of every view. They should all overlap. (Unless you left out the code that calculates your sq rectangle? If you did that, then show that code, since it is no doubt important to figuring out the problem.)

Why not assign a tag to each of these views, using i? That would help you see if the views are getting scrambled somehow.

Comment: I changed the code to use NSMutableArray like others have suggested and it worked. I am not adding the same CGRect for all the views. Also, I see the board is rendered correctly. So the problem is in the array creation. Why can I not create a C array for objects? More so, is there a way to create an array of objects without using NSArray or NSMutableArray?